# Why memory consumption grows?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Here is a very simple piece of code:

```
- (void)functionOne
 {
   [self performSelector:@selector(functionTwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
 }
- (void)functionTwo
 {
   [self performSelector:@selector(functionOne) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
 }
```

As you can see there's nothing in these two methods what could cause growth of memory consumption. But it grows. Very slowly, but it does. About 0.01 MB every three seconds. Why? How can i avoid it?

Comment: Isn't this technically just an infinite loop?

Comment: yes, but should it cause memory growth?

Comment: Can you explain how and why you are using the methods above? Does memory still get consumed when you set the withObject:self?

Comment: i switch state of an object every second

Comment: This is an infinite loop, but a very slow one ;-)  Does the memory ever stop growing?

Comment: Each method is waiting for a response from the other, which builds up an infinite amount of times unless you manually stop it.  Try setting the delay to 0 seconds, you'll probably have to force quit.  If you want to switch states, try calling a method every second and using an if/else statement.

Comment: it never stops. it even increases speed of growth i would say

Comment: Only use performSelector: when the selector returns an object. If the selector returns a struct, then you risk corrupting memory, even if you don’t use the return value. If the method doesn’t return an object, then use NSInvocation instead, because it is capable of determining the correct message dispatch function to use. http://tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/why-performselector-is-more-dangerous-than-i-thought/

Comment: Did you try your solution withObject:self as I suggested?

Comment: @MarkM no, i didn't. i don't understand what you're talking about

Answer (score 3):

You are effectively creating an infinite loop.  If you want to switch the state of an object every one second (as you said in the comments), do it this way:

Create a method like so:

```
- (void)functionOne
{
    if( [obj isEqual:stateA] ) {
        obj = stateB;
    } else {
        obj = stateA;
    }
}
```

and call it with a timer:

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self
                               selector:@selector(functionOne) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Your solution helped me partly. it has slowed the growth

Comment: Hmm, it's kind of hard to judge without knowing exactly what you're doing.  Perhaps edit the original question with the actual code if possible?  You may also have a memory leak in addition to this one.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid infinite loops you should use a `NSTimer` and one function, in which you toggle the state of your object.

in your init method, or something like `viewDidLoad` you should start a timer like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(switchState:)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];
}
```

then you use one method like

```
- (void) switchState:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if ([[self yourState] isEqual:stateOne]) {
        [self setYourState:stateTwo];
    } else {
        [self setYourState:stateOne];
    }
}
```

for more information see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Answer (score 0):

The memory grows simply because the Application needs to hold onto some state. Each time you call perform selector that selector is pushed onto the stack. This stack is saved in memory. Hence the growth.

Comment: By stack I mean the Runtime Stack.

Comment: You should rephrase the question if you are looking for alternative solutions @AndreyChernukha

Comment: How do i make two functions call each other with a certain delay without causing growth of memory consumption?

Comment: As others have suggested, use a timer that calls a method that checks and changes the state of the object on each call. By doing this you are not adding to the stack on each call as atreat mentioned. Otherwise your method is holding the state on each call over and over (infinite loop).